# highway captions not show in zoom level 14 mapsforge

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik, mapsforge

I am using a Mapsforge map, and I have a question about my map file. In my map, highway captions are not shown at zoom level 14 and even in higher zoom and this causes my map to be unclear,but when I see the map in forexample bbbike.org in mapnik form the captions are exist.. I have searched, and so far found nothing about this problem

Comment: This should be a configuration option in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

The default Rendertheme mapsforge uses osmarenderer.xml has set the caption for highway for minimum zoom level of 15.

If you want to show the caption you need to create your own Rendertheme and copy osmarenderer.xml and change zoom-min="15" of highway.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I've done that before and it couldn't help me thanks anyway